# C++/TCP data transfer garbage

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm a beginner C++/TCP programmer and I was doing a home assignment for file transfer using TCP in C++/VS2010/Windows 7.

I've created a client and a server that can listen to multiple clients on a network.
When I send a request to the server requesting a file, I receive the correct size of file, but when I send data from server to client I get garbage.

I'm pretty sure I've done a stupid mistake somewhere with casting, but can't identify where.
I am sending `char*` byte by byte and save them to a file on the client.

Any ideas what's wrong?

```
// client code: 
unsigned int packlen = 0;
unsigned int flength = 0;
char* data = NULL;
if((packlen = recv(sock, (char*) &flength, sizeof(unsigned int), 0)) == 
    sizeof(unsigned int))
{
    flength = (unsigned int) flength;
    data = new char[flength];
}
unsigned char current;
char* buffer;
unsigned int accumlength = 0;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < flength; ++i)
{
    if((packlen = recv(sock, (char*) &current , sizeof(unsigned int), 0)) 
        != sizeof(unsigned int))
    {
        err_sys("Receiving packet transfer error., exit");
    }
    data[i] = current;
}
ofstream output(argv[2], ios::binary);
output.write(data, flength);
if(data)
{
    delete[] data;
    data = NULL;
}


// Server code:
char* data = NULL;
unsigned long length;
string fname; 

data = new char[stat_buf.st_size];
ifstream input(reqp->filename, ios::binary);
input.seekg(0, ios::end);
unsigned int length = input.tellg();
if(length != stat_buf.st_size)
{
    err_sys("Problems with file size");
}

send(cs, (char*) &length, sizeof(unsigned int), 0);
Sleep(1000);  // wait a bit

input.read(data, length); // read all file at once.
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    unsigned char current = data[i];
    send(cs, (char*) &current, sizeof(unsigned char), 0);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `recv(sock, (char*) &current , sizeof(unsigned int), 0)` looks completely odd. `current` is a single char, you can't read an `unsigned int`'s worth of data into it unless you have very large chars.

Comment: You are sending one `unsigned char` for each byte on the server side but receiving `unsigned int` on the client side.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake for the incorrect type match.

Comment: Now I'm doing this: 
         for(unsigned int i = 0; i < flength; ++i)
            {
                if((packlen = recv(sock, (char*) &current , sizeof(unsigned   char), 0)) != sizeof(unsigned char))
          {
           err_sys("Receiving packet transfer error., exit");
          }
       data[i] = current;
      }

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are discarding quite a few bytes during the read loop:

```
recv(sock, (char*) &current, sizeof(unsigned int), 0)
```

Where `current` is an unsigned char but you ask it to read `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes which are more than that. So recv() will write its result somewhere else (because it will write 4 bytes in `current`)

You should probably write:

```
recv(sock, (char*) &current, 1, 0)
```

Even though that is terribly inefficient it should at least work.

Comment: I've did that, but it's still garbage... I transfer one jpg file byte by byte using send(cs, (char*) &current, 1, 0); on the server and recv(sock, (char*) &current , 1, 0) on the client with garbage as a result... I don't understand why...